# Proving $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-2\pi i k (x-a)}dk=\delta(x-a)$ with this method

Tags: fourier-transform, dirac-delta

I want to prove $$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-2\pi i k (x-a)}dk=\delta(x-a)$$
By following the following logic:
$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-2\pi i k (x-a)}dk$$
equals $0$ whenever $x\ne a$ and $\infty$ when $x=a$

So the next step would be to prove that
$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-2\pi i k (x-a)}dk dx=1$$
I've tried to begin by separating it as
$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{2\pi i k a}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-2\pi i k x}dx dk$$
But I am stuck. Please help.

Comment: and why would $$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-2\pi i k (x-a)}dk dx=1$$ imply that $$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-2\pi i k (x-a)}dk=\delta(x-a)$$ ????

Comment: Because the properties of the Dirac-Delta function are that $\delta (x-a)$ is zero everywhere except for $x=a$ where it has infinite value, and it's integral over all of $x$ equals one. Since $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-2\pi i k (x-a)}dk$ is zero everywhere except when $x=a$, we only need to prove that it's integral is equal to one, and it'll have the same properties of the Dirac-Delta function, and therefore be equal to the Dirac-Delta function.

Comment: Also, it is known that $$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-2\pi i k (x-a)}dk=\delta(x-a)$$ from Fourier Analysis, I just want to prove it in a different way.

Comment: This $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-2\pi i k (x-a)}dk=\delta(x-a)$ is correct and here is one way of proving it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2930585/fourier-transform-of-fx-ei2-pi-ax/2930598#2930598.


 But trying to prove it by proving $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-2\pi i k (x-a)}dk dx=1$ is wrong. Do you see why ?

Comment: I don't quite understand why. Care to elucidate?

Comment: What is even the definition of the LHS ? The Fourier transform of 1 as a tempered distribution ?

Answer (score 0):

We need to show that for any test function $\phi(x)$ that

$$\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)\int_{-L}^L e^{-i2\pi k(x-a)}\,dk\,dx=\phi(a)$$

Proceeding, we have for any $\epsilon>0$

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)\int_{-L}^L e^{-i2\pi k(x-a)}\,dk\,dx&=\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)\left(\frac{\sin(2\pi (x-a)L)}{\pi (x-a)}\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x+a)\left(\frac{\sin(2\pi xL)}{\pi x}\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\lim_{L\to\infty}\left(\int_{|x|\le \epsilon}\phi(x+a)\left(\frac{\sin(2\pi xL)}{\pi x}\right)\,dx\right.\\\\
&+\left.\int_{|x|\ge \epsilon}\phi(x+a)\left(\frac{\sin(2\pi xL)}{\pi x}\right)\,dx\right)\tag1\\\\
&=\lim_{L\to\infty}\int_{|x|\le L\epsilon}\phi(x/L+a)\left(\frac{\sin(2\pi x)}{\pi x}\right)\,dx\tag2\\\\
&=\lim_{L\to\infty}\int_{|x|\le L\epsilon}\left(\phi(a)+O\left(\frac xL\right)\right)\left(\frac{\sin(2\pi x)}{\pi x}\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\phi(a)+O(\epsilon)\tag3
\end{align}$$

In going from $(1)$ to $(2)$, we applied the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma.

Finally, since, $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, we may take the limit as $\epsilon\to 0$ of $(3)$ to find that

$$\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)\int_{-L}^L e^{-i2\pi k(x-a)}\,dk\,dx=\phi(a)$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Hi.  Would you please let me know how I can improve my answer? I really want to give you the best answer I can.  If this was not useful, I am happy to delete it.  Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: And feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit.  ;-)